# Comparing rows in pandas and filling empty entries

Tags: pandas, csv, comparison

I pretty much just want to fill in the 1000 from the last two rows in the yellow fields, with the help of the column of the customer and Product name. In excel i would just do a Vlookup [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6pdA.png)

I have a file with orders and must fill in empty entries in a csv file. 
I already know, how to fill in empty entries with a value i choose:

`df.loc[df['BillingsandBacklogs'].isnull(), 'BillingsandBacklogs'] = 'my_value'`

Those empty entries are orders, which I need to compare with other rows in my file.

I have columns for `SAPMatnr` and `SAPCustomer`, which have the correct entry in the column `BillingsandBacklogs`. And there are rows with the same entries in `SAPMatnr` and `SAPCustomer` but have empty entries in `BillingsandBacklogs`
Now I have to copy the value which is not empty from `BillingsandBacklogs` into the rows which are empty, but have the same Matnr and Customer.

[excerpt from my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6pdA.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can try using `groupby` and both `ffill` and `bfill`.:

```
df['BillingsandBacklogs'] = df[['SAPMatnr', 'SAPCustomer', 'BillingsandBacklogs']].groupby(['SAPMatnr', 'SAPCustomer'])['BillingsandBacklogs'].apply(lambda x: x.bfill().ffill())
```

Comment: I think you understood it, but i edited the picture in the original question.
So the only unique identifier would be the delivery week with the diff load due week. So if i would fill in forward from line 13, it would paste the value in the lines below, where it is not supposed to be, as it is a different week and therefore a different order. 
The only unique identifier would be the customer+product name+ delivery week+ diff load due week.